# RCV1 dataset classification with Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, keras, lstm

I'm having issues training a text classifier using LSTM on the RCV1-v2 dataset,and after a thorough search I still don't know how to input the data to my model.

I'm using the fetch_rcv1() function from sklearn (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/rcv1.html), which states the following:

data: The feature matrix is a scipy CSR sparse matrix, with 804414 samples and 47236 features.

target: The target values are stored in a scipy CSR sparse matrix, with 804414 samples and 103 categories.

sample_id: Each sample can be identified by its ID, ranging (with gaps) from 2286 to 810596:

Note that a document can belong to multiple categories,thus making the problem multilabel.According to the above ,train shape is (23149,47236) =>23149 documents with 47236 TF-IDF  vectors

Unfortunately there's no clear explanation or any tutorial whatsoever(even after days of searching!!) on how to manipulate the data. I'm trying to insert the data to a LSTM layer to no success.The model keeps failing to compile,example given:

```
Train on 23149 samples, validate on 781265 samples
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/laxius/PycharmProjects/rcv1/rcv1.py", line 31, in <module>
validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 672, in fit
initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1192, in fit
initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 892, in _fit_loop
outs = f(ins_batch)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 1900, in __call__
feed_dict=feed_dict)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 766, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 937, in _run
np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 531, in asarray
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Can anyone guide me on how I should reshape the data/layers to get the model to compile?Here's my code attempt so far:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_rcv1
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Embedding
from keras.layers import LSTM


train = fetch_rcv1(subset='train')
test = fetch_rcv1(subset='test')

X_train = train.data
X_test = test.data


y_train = train.target
y_test = test.target

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=(None,47236),output_dim=300,dropout=0.25))
model.add(LSTM(350, dropout_W=0.4, dropout_U=0.4))  
model.add(Dense(103))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer='adam',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

print('Train...')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, nb_epoch=15,
      validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
score, acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test,
                        batch_size=32)
print('Test score:', score)
print('Test accuracy:', acc)
```

Comment: Sorry,forgot to add that.Editting. It's :
>>> train.data.shape

(23149, 47236)

According to the documentation it should be 

2D tensor with shape: (nb_samples, sequence_length).

Comment: Yes - sorry - it was for LSTM layer - not embedding. Is every feature - an integer?

Comment: SKLearn doc says it's TF-IDF vectors so I assume they are float,precisely dtype np.float64.I could always skip the embedding layer(which I'm trying)but then it complains about the ndim of the LSTM layer->expected 3 dimensions but got array with shape (23149,47236)

Comment: Why are you using sigmoid? Shouldn't it be a softmax activation?

Comment: The problem is multilabel,isn't softmax used for multiclass(mutually exclusive)?The target vectors have multiple 1s and zeros

Comment: And how about trying "categorical_crossentropy" instead of "binary_crossentropy"?

Comment: If you check this https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/741, it states that for multilabel classification you need output layer to be sigmoid and binary_crossentropy for loss,since it computes the typical log-loss of the model.I think I'll have to deep a bit digger to get the data shaped in an input that keras accepts, the problem must be with the SKLearn CSR sparse matrices.

Comment: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence means you are feeding the sequences with different sequence lengths, pad it.